# I can't boot into single user mode

Tags: macos, mac, disk-utility, partition, unix

A while back I partitioned my hard drive into two equal parts. I completely forgot about it and then realized that I only had half of my original drive space available. I startup disk utility and attempt to shrink the second partition to a much more reasonable 100GB. However, when I tried this I got an error message that read "partition failed error. couldn't modify partition map because file system verification failed." So I do a little research and try to boot in single user mode in order to fix the problem. But when I do i'm met with a screen that looks like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This problem has been fixed. Turns out rEFit had something to do with my boot commands. However if you press f2 when selecting your drive it will give you an option to boot in single-user mode